# Get results from objects in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I have this controller:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $id=$request->get('id');
        if($id)
        {
            $show=Crud::where('id',$id)->get();
            echo json_encode(array('status' => TRUE,  'show'=>$show)); die;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
}
```

And this jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{url('/crud/show')}}",
        data: {id:id},
        success: function (data) {
        var res = $.parseJSON(data);
        //console.log(res.show);
        if(res.status == true)
           {       
                //console.log(res.show.name);
                var result = 'Name:'+res.show.name+'<br>'+
                             'Phone:'+res.show.phone+'<br>'+
                             'Class:'+res.show.class+'<br>'+
                             'Address:'+res.show.address+'<br>'+
                    $('#result').html(result);  
            }
        }
    });          
});
```

`res.show.name`, `res.show.address` etc. are not giving values. If i use the raw sql query there is no problem. I guess the raw sql query gives the result in array while eloquent method gives the result in object. Is that making the difference?How should i deal with this?
`console.log(res.show);` gives this if i click on any show class.

```
    [Object]0:
    Object
     address: "Maharishi"
     class: 123
     id: 7
     name: "Maharjan"
     phone: "123456789"
   __proto__: Object
     length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

while `console.log(res.show.name);` displays undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `console.log(res.show.name);` displays undefined.

How about `console.log(res.show[0].name);` ?

You are calling `Crud::where('id',$id)->get();` which gives a Collection of all "Crud" object with that id. That Collection is serialized to a JSON array. So, get the first element of the array first.

Or even better, since you probably know by design that only 1 object has that id, `Crud::where('id',$id)->first();` Then you can `res.show.name`.

Finally, your controller could be like this:

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $response = ['status' => false];

    if ($request->ajax())
    {
        if ($id = $request->id)
        {
            if ($show = Crud::where('id', $id)->first())
                    // same as Crud::find($id);
            {
                $response = ['status' => true, 'show' => $show];
            }
        }
    }

    return response()->json($response);
}
```

(same functionality, more idiomatic to the framework)

Answer (score 1):

When response in only in JSON format, you can set `dataType:'json'` in ajax options no need to parse it using `JSON.parse()` method.

```
$(document).on('click', '.show', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{url('/crud/show')}}",
        data: {id:id},
        dataType: 'json'
        success: function (res) {
        //console.log(res.show);
        if(res.status == true)
           {       
                //console.log(res.show.name);
                var result = 'Name:'+res.show.name+'<br>'+
                             'Phone:'+res.show.phone+'<br>'+
                             'Class:'+res.show.class+'<br>'+
                             'Address:'+res.show.address+'<br>'+
                    $('#result').html(result);  
            }
        }
    });          
});
```

As per you mentioned in your question "If i use the raw sql query there is no problem. I guess the raw sql query gives the result in array while eloquent method gives the result in object."

For this can I know what structure of your response come in result object?